# Error naming file with content of variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to name a file with the content of one variable doing this script

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
file=mails.txt
lines=$(cat ${file})

for line in ${lines}; do
   echo "'${line}'"
   final=echo "'$line'" |sed -e 's/^\.\*\(.*\)\*\./\1/'
   curl -XGET "https://google.es" > $final.'.txt'
   sleep 2
 done

 IFS=""
 exit ${?}
```

The content of mails.txt is something like:

```
 .*john*.
 .*peter*.
```

And when I do that I have the error `./testcur.sh line 7: .john*. :order not found`, the same with peter. How can I do to name the files john.txt and peter.txt

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three mistakes

- "'$line'" -> "$line"
- final=echo -> final=$(echo ...)
- $final.'.txt' -> $final'.txt'

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
file=mails.txt
lines=$(cat ${file})

for line in ${lines}; do
   echo "'${line}'"
   final=$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/^\.\*\(.*\)\*\./\1/')
   curl -XGET "https://google.es" > ${final}'.txt'                         
   sleep 2
done

IFS=""
exit ${?}
```